# ping external host from zabbix agent

Tags: external, ping, agent, zabbix

We are running a typical zabbix server setup. A zabbix server and a couple linux servers that has zabbix agent installed and monitored by the zabbix server. However, my problem is there a way to check ping (icmppingsec maybe? :confused:) in between linux_host A to linux_host B and output the result to the zabbix server coming from linux_host A??

I have tried simple check `icmppingsec[<target>,<packets>,<interval>,<size>,<timeout>,<mode>]` but I found out that the ping is executed by the zabbix server itself and not the host A.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution to add this user parameter:

```
UserParameter=chk.fping[*],sudo /usr/bin/fping -c 3 $1 2>&1 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d '/' -f2
```

Add permission in /etc/sudoers because of an error when creating SOCKET.

`zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/fping`

In the template, you can add items you'd like to ping.

`chk.fping[8.8.8.8]`

Comment: This works, make sure to define in items your type information as "Numeric (float)", otherwise the result will be treated as string.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the ability to ping a host by Zabbix agent is not supported out of the box, but there is a feature request for that: [ZBXNEXT-739](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-739). Meanwhile, you should add a user parameter on the agent that would do the pinging.

Comment: thank you for the info, i did my research and found how to ping thru userparameters using this code `UserParameter=<key>,fping x.x.x.x | grep alive | wc -l` but it only outputs 1 and 0, is there a way to output a response time and graph it on zabbix server?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get the ping latency from the zabbix agent in order to ping an external host. I declared this parameter to the zabbix_agentd.conf

```
UserParameter=key_name[*],fping -e x.x.x.x | awk '{ print $4 }' | tr -d '('
```

It outputs the response time, numeric value only. My next problem is how to make this command readable by zabbix server so that it will be viewable thru graph. On zabbix server the output is ***"no data"*** but under *Hosts > Items*, it is green and enabled.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that if you use a user parameter with arguments, then in the `awk` command you should use $$4 instead of $4. Otherwise, Zabbix agent will try to substitute $4 with the item's fourth argument, which is probably empty. If you have the IP hardcoded into the command, just omit "[*]" in the key name. See https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/userparameters for more information on user parameters.